# 3 cables into a 2 switch box

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling, ceiling-fan

My breaker keeps tripping because of this wiring and/or faulty switches and now with a new switch, my ceiling fan won’t turn but the light still works and it still trips. I’m trying to figure out how to make this safe, because there is no way the current set up from the builders is correct.  I have attached pictures for reference. Any help on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated. Currently, the left switch controls the bathroom lights and the right switch controls the vent fan. I’m assuming the ceiling fan in the bedroom is connected in somewhere as it stopped working when one switch was simply replaced.  [image]

Comment: B1 and 2 are currently to the left switch, B3 is to the right and there is a “jumper black from the left switch to the right. The whites are nutted off, and the 3 grounds are twisted together with only 1 long enough to reach the switches. It is currently running to both switches.

Comment: When did the breaker _start_ tripping?  A bad switch won't make a breaker trip (assuming it's not a AFCI breaker).  Just because turning this switch on makes the breaker trip, doesn't mean the problem is in that box.

Comment: It’s a GFCI breaker. I originally replaced it and it kept tripping. After replacing the one light switch, it stopped tripping for a few weeks, but tripped again yesterday.

Comment: Is it tripping for GFCI, or is it tripping for overcurrent? The breaker should have an indicator to show which.  And, we need to know to give an intelligent answer that isn't a string of "If A then B, if C then D, if E then F" etc.

Comment: Our GFCI breaker doesn’t have an indicator. It just trips and shows orange. I can test it by flipping it and timing how long it takes to trip according the the breaker. It was tripping automatically after I flipped it until I replaced the light switch shown above. And then tripped again yesterday. Thank you for your responses. I’m not the most comfortable with wiring but I have a decent base of knowledge.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box?